# Why do I can slide to more than two times while I have only two tabs on Android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-tabs

I am learning how to use navigation drawer and navigation tab. I created an app that implement a navigation drawer on MainActivity and each item on navigation drawer will replace fragment on MainActivity to the corresponding fragment.

My first fragment provide two navigation tab using [SlidingTabLayout](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabLayout.java) and [SlidingTabStrip](https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/0a90bf8e6b90e9226f8c15b34eb7b1e4bf6d632e/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/ui/widget/SlidingTabStrip.java). The other fragments are just a textview.

If I move from the first item to the second item and then back to first item again, my tab still show two tab, but in fact, I can slide more than two times and the content is not shown.

How do I fix this?

What it should be:

[image]
[image]

After I move to second drawer and then back to first drawer:

[image]
[image]

What happened after that:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

You can see that I can slide more than twice and the content of fragments are not shown.

**MainActivity.java**

```js
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    String titles[] = {"TabsFragment", "TextFragment"};
    Fragment fragment[] = {TabsFragment.newInstance(), TextFragment.newInstance()};

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    static View.OnClickListener drawerItemClickListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerView);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mAdapter = new DrawerAdapter(titles);

        drawerItemClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int selectedPos = mRecyclerView.getChildPosition(v);
                drawer.closeDrawers();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment[selectedPos])
                        .commit();
            }
        };

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this,
                drawer,
                toolbar,
                R.string.open_drawer,
                R.string.close_drawer) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);

                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);

                supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        drawer.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_content, fragment[0])
                    .commit();
        }
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```html
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout">

    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**TabsFragment.java**

```js
public class TabsFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        TabsFragment fragment = new TabsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tabs, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
        SlidingTabLayout mSlidingTabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        mSlidingTabLayout.setViewPager(mViewPager);
    }

    class SamplePagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        private String[] tabTitles = new String[] {"Tab One", "Tab Two"};
        private Context context;

        public SamplePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
            super(fm);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabTitles.length;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabTitles[position];
        }


        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            android.support.v4.app.Fragment[] fragment = {TabOneFragment.newInstance(), TabTwoFragment.newInstance()};

            return fragment[position];
        }

    }
}
```

**fragment_tabs.xml**

```html
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TabsFragment">

    <android.com.drawertab.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/sliding_tabs" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**TabsOneFragment.java**

```js
public class TabOneFragment extends Fragment{

    public static TabOneFragment newInstance() {
        TabOneFragment fragment = new TabOneFragment();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_tabs_one.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="TAB ONE" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**TabsTwoFragment.java**

```js
public class TabTwoFragment extends Fragment {

    public static TabTwoFragment newInstance() {
        TabTwoFragment fragment = new TabTwoFragment();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_tabs_two.java**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="TAB TWO" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**TextFragment.java**

```js
public class TextFragment extends Fragment {

    public static Fragment newInstance() {
        TextFragment fragment = new TextFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_text, container, false);
    }
}
```

**fragment_text.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text="FRAGMENT TEXT" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**DrawerAdapter.java**

```js
public class DrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private String mNavTitles[];

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView,int ViewType) {
            super(itemView);

            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowText);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.drawerItemClickListener);
        }
    }

    public DrawerAdapter(String[] titles) {
        mNavTitles = titles;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_item_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vhItem = new ViewHolder(v, viewType);

        return vhItem;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(mNavTitles[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNavTitles.length;
    }
}
```

**drawer_item_row.xml**

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:id="@+id/rowText" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are correct about sliding more times than twice, then you need to set the override method **getCount** correctly (I realize you know). That's the only issue you need to worry about.

```
private String[] tabTitles = new String[] {"Tab One", "Tab Two"};
...
     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return tabTitles.length;
     }
```

Note: I declared tabTitles differently as an array of String "String[]", widely accepted. The other style "tabTitles[]" may not work well with its methods like length.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code more closely, I suspect objects `TabOneFragment` and `TabTwoFragment` is not working well. Normally override **getItem** returns the same static Fragment. And of course, I do not see that declaration or code for it.

My suggested try is (from your code):

```
@Override
public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
   return TabsFragment.newInstance(position);
}
```

Note: With the above code, I don't see any use for `TabOneFragment` and `TabTwoFragment`, referenced in `getItem(int position)` in `SamplePagerAdapter` class. The TextView UI in layout **fragment_tab_one.xml** is only used for the tab texts. For those texts, the override `getPageTitle(int position)` can be used and is already coded.

Comment: TabOneFragment and TabTwoFragment are two other fragments. I didn't show the code there because I think it's just a textview. I want my app show  the textview when the user click the tab.

Comment: TabOneFragment is a Fragment, no less, not a Textview. So perhaps that code needs to change.

Comment: For debugging purposes, try my suggested code and see if the odd behavior still appears. I'll edit my post to make a certain point.

Comment: I've uploaded my code on Github in case you want to try it yourself. I would be feel so thankful if you are able to help me. https://github.com/stackex/DrawerTab